# maximum websocket clients are limited in node js websocket server

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, websocket

i m trying to simulate multiple client connections to my websocket server hosted at aws server.

here's is the code i did so far :

```
var count =0;

function foo(){
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://<myserverip>:<serverport>/');

ws.on('open', function () {

    ws.send('some json data');
    console.log("connection opened : ",count++);
    ws.on('message',function(message) {
        console.log('Message received by client %s : %s',count.toString() , message );
    });

    ws.on('close',function(){
        console.log("connection closed.clients left : ",count-- );
    });

    ws.on('error',function(e){
        console.log("error occured : ",e );
    });
});
}
```

the problem is i cannot open more than 238 clients from my machine. after that i get connection close with error 500 on client side and 1006 on server side. How can i create more connections from local  machine and why do i get this error?